# Pandas: I am trying to open a specific .txt file stored in a zip file on an ftp site

Tags: python, pandas, ftp, zip

I need to concatenate---into a single  frame---every `produkt_monat_Monatswerte_18910101_20110331_00003.txt` file in each of the zip files from [this](ftp://ftp-cdc.dwd.de/pub/CDC/observations_germany/climate/monthly/kl/historical/) ftp site.

This is the code that I am using so far:

```
    import pandas as pd
    from pandas.io.parsers import *
    import glob
    import requests
    from zipfile import ZipFile
    import urllib.request as ur


    years = 'produkt_monat_Monatswerte_*.txt'

names = pd.DataFrame()
for year in years:
    path ="ftp://ftp-cdc.dwd.de/pub/CDC/observations_germany/climate/monthly/kl/historical/monatswerte_?????_????????_????????_hist.zip").read()
    frame = pd.read_csv(path, names=columns)

    frame['year'] = year
    names = names.concat(frame, ignore_index=True)
```

and it is giving me the following error:

```
 File "<ipython-input-25-d57a1d77ecc6>", line 5
    path ="ftp://ftp-cdc.dwd.de/pub/CDC/observations_germany/climate/monthly/kl/historical/monatswerte_?????_????????_????????_hist.zip")
```

Comment: Your first issue is the `glob` bit it can't open the file, you need to resolve that step first before pandas can even attempt to open it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you can't have pandas extract an inner file from the Zip.
Try the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from ftplib import FTP
import os
from zipfile import ZipFile
from io import BytesIO

f_root = 'ftp-cdc.dwd.de'
zips_path = '/pub/CDC/observations_germany/climate/monthly/kl/historical/'

ftp = FTP(f_root)

ftp.login()

ftp.cwd(zips_path)

paths = [p[0] for p in ftp.mlsd('.') if p[0].endswith('.zip')]

dfs = []

for path in paths:
    buf = BytesIO()
    ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + path, lambda block: buf.write(block))
    z = ZipFile(buf)

    zi = list(filter(lambda x: x.filename.startswith('produkt'), z.filelist))[0]
    df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(z.read(zi.filename)), sep=';', encoding="cp1252")
    dfs.append(df)

final = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. How can I create a loop to concat over all of them

Comment: `dfs = []

for path in paths:
    buf = BytesIO()
    ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + path, lambda block: buf.write(block))
    z = ZipFile(buf)

    zi = list(filter(lambda x: x.filename.startswith('produkt'), z.filelist))[0]
    df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(z.read(zi.filename)), sep=';', encoding="cp1252")
    dfs.append(df)
    
final = pd.concat(dfs)` (comment is a bit messed up, iv'e simply added a loop.)

Comment: Thank You! :) Do you think that you can update your answer with this ^ comment?

Comment: I have updated you answer with your comment above. Could you please take a look at it. It is giving me an error.

Comment: yes the spaces got messed up in the commets... edited it now.